# ip route mentinoning GW

Tags: networking, ip, routing

My intention is to ping from a network namespace to a machine which sits beyond a GW. For that I have created one network namespace, I set the ip route inside the namespace and in the global namespace. When I set the ip route inside the namespace without mentioning "GW"(via) my tcpdump at the global namespace interface(the one which is connected to GW) showed the "ARP requests to identify the ip". However when I set the ip route inside namespace with "GW"(via) (ip route add x.x.x.x/x via xx.xx.xx.xx dev my_namespace_veth_adapter ), it worked perfectly and I was able to ping to the other machine. How a route with and without GW is interpreted ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the answer:

- Routes without a gateway mean that the destination host is reachable directly, in other words it's "on link", so the system will ARP for it directly.
- Routes *with* a gateway mean that the destination host *isn't* reachable directly, so the system will ARP for the gateway's address instead.